# How do you create files with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Force download of ‘data:text/plain’ URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468517/force-download-of-datatext-plain-url)
>   [Create a downloadable link from a vriable in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355750/create-a-downloadable-link-from-a-vriable-in-javascript)

I have seen plugins that can create/generate files (.txt, .pdf, .vcard) and I'm not exactly sure how it's done. Are these done through Ajax? Or is there an object/method I'm missing?

Comment: Is it possible to do this only using client side?

Comment: Only with FileSystem API but I am not sure thats what you are looking for... Do you have a site with an example?

Comment: In order to create files on the user's computer, you generally create a binary string with the file data and then redirect the page to a [`data:` URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) with the base64-encoded file data, so the browser can download it.

Comment: @adeneo, your statement "you'll need ajax, as javascript" makes no sense.  Javascript is what drives AJAX.

Comment: Here are some examples: http://badassjs.com/post/708922912/pdf-js-create-pdfs-in-javascript

https://github.com/mattt/vcard.js

Comment: Maybe you should expand if you want to create the files on the server side or on the client computer's filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

Html5 does support access to File System. Below link has a good example:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Comment: Nice! This is very helpful, but I'm curious how people have been able to generate files before HTML5 was available. Also, since this isn't widely supported yet.

Comment: Generating file *data* and prompting the creation of an *actual file* are two separate steps. Direct your browser to `data:text/x-plain,helloworldfoobar` and you'll see it's quite easy to prompt for a download, once you have your file data created. Generating file data is roughly the same as generating any kind of data in any language: move some bits and bytes around until they look how you want.

Comment: On a microsoft machines, via VBScript for example, you can do the following:  Set fso = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject") ...  that only worked on ie.  I think there was a similar way to do so in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the spec for the [FS API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/). Unfortunately [support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=filesystem) for it is very light.
Though, if you want to use it in mobile apps, PhoneGap has [implement it](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File).

If you write a GreaseMonkey script you have [GM_xmlhttpRequest](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest) which doesn't have the same origin policy.